# How to break down the following command, so it can be used in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a Bash script for a custom rofi menu. This menu would have different choices for different custom commands.  Currently, I am trying to see if I can write a Bash script to execute a single command. The command is:

```
exec /home/user/.config/i3/myscript.sh 'todolist' 'xfce4-terminal --command "emacs -nw -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/script.el ~/Dropbox/mytodo.org" '
```

This is a very long command so I break it down like this:

```
COMMAND=("/home/user/.config/i3/myscript.sh")                                                                                                                         
EMACS=(" 'todolist' 'xfce4-terminal --command "emacs -nw -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/script.el ~/Dropbox/mytodo.org"' ")
```

I tried to echo out: `echo $COMMAND $EMACS`. The result I got is:

```
/home/user/.config/i3/script.sh 'todolist' 'xfce4-terminal --command emacs
```

So, everything from the `-nw -Q -l` forward are ignored. As a result, it is an incomplete command. How can I fix the second variable EMACS?

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses in a variable assignment in Bash are used to create arrays. The array items are separated by space. Here's an example:

```
arr=(0 1 2)
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}
```

So in your case:

```
EMACS=(" 'todolist' 'xfce4-terminal --command "emacs -nw -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/script.el ~/Dropbox/mytodo.org"' ")
```

The expression `${EMACS[0]}` will contain  `'todolist' 'xfce4-terminal --command emacs`, the expression `${EMACS[1]}` will have the value `-nw`, and so on.

Also, notice that `" 'todolist' etc. "emacs` is just the juxtaposition of the strings `" 'todolist' etc. "` and `emacs`, so the result will be the concatenation of all characters without the quotes.

My suggestion is that you use variables for the files and keep the rest in plain bash. Use a backslash to break the command into multiple lines if you feel one line is too long:

```
MY_SCRIPT="${HOME}/.config/i3/myscript.sh"
EMACS_SCRIPT="${HOME}/.emacs.d/script.el"
DROPBOX_FILE="${HOME}/mytodo.org"
exec "$MY_SCRIPT" todolist xfce4-terminal \
    --command "emacs -nw -Q -l ${EMACS_SCRIPT} ${DROPBOX_FILE}"
```

Comment: If you do `EMACS_CMD="emacs -nw -Q -l ${EMACS_SCRIPT} ${DROPBOX_FILE}"`, then `exec "$MY_SCRIPT" todolist xfce4-terminal --command "$EMACS_CMD"`...

Comment: Or you could build some bash arrays: `exec "${MY_SCRIPT[@]}"`